# Pass multiple images data from JavaScript to PHP to Preview and Upload multiple images with delete option

Tags: javascript, php

I want to be able to pass images from Javasctipt to PHP then upload them and store them in MySQL.

```html
<div class="media">
    <div class="aspect-ratio">
        <div class="previewcon">
            <div class="preview" id="preview1con">
                <img id="preview1" src="" alt="">
                <i id="remove1" class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="preview" id="preview4con">
                <img id="preview4" src="" alt="">
                <i id="remove4" class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="previewcon" id="previewcon">
            <div class="preview" id="preview2con">
                <img id="preview2" src="" alt="">
                <i id="remove2" class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="preview" id="preview3con">
                <img id="preview3" src="" alt="">
                <i id="remove3" class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
    <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon-input">
        <i class="fas fa-photo-video i-hover-s current"></i>
        <input id="media-input" name="media-array[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp,image/gif,video/mp4,video/quicktime,video/webm" onchange="mediaSelect()" multiple>
    </div>
        <script>
            const mediaUploading = document.getElementById("media-uploading");
            var medias = [];
            function mediaSelect(){
                var media = document.getElementById("media-input").files;
                
                for(i = 0; i < media.length; i++){
                    if(medias.length >= 4){
                    }
                    else{
                        medias.push({
                            "name" : media[i].name,
                            "url" : URL.createObjectURL(media[i]),
                            "file" : media[i]
                        });
                    }
                }

                if(medias[0]){
                    mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                    preview1.src = medias[0]["url"];
                    mediaCon.style.display = "block";
                    preview2con.style.display = "none";
                    preview3con.style.display = "none";
                    preview4con.style.display = "none";
                    previewcon.style.display = "none";
                    preview1con.style.display = "block";
                    preview1con.style.height = "100%";
                    if(medias[1]){
                        preview2.src = medias[1]["url"];
                        preview2con.style.display = "block";
                        previewcon.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "100%";
                    }
                    if(medias[2]){
                        preview3.src = medias[2]["url"];
                        preview3con.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                    if(medias[3]){
                        preview4.src = medias[3]["url"];
                        preview4con.style.display = "block";
                        preview1con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                } 
            }


            remove1.addEventListener("click", () =>{
                mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                medias.splice(0, 1);
                preview1con.style.display = "none";
                if(!medias[0]){    
                    mediaCon.style.display = "none";
                }
                if(medias[0]){
                    mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                    preview1.src = medias[0]["url"];
                    mediaCon.style.display = "block";
                    preview2con.style.display = "none";
                    preview3con.style.display = "none";
                    preview4con.style.display = "none";
                    previewcon.style.display = "none";
                    preview1con.style.display = "block";
                    preview1con.style.height = "100%";
                    if(medias[1]){
                        preview2.src = medias[1]["url"];
                        preview2con.style.display = "block";
                        previewcon.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "100%";
                    }
                    if(medias[2]){
                        preview3.src = medias[2]["url"];
                        preview3con.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                    if(medias[3]){
                        preview4.src = medias[3]["url"];
                        preview4con.style.display = "block";
                        preview1con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                }
            })

            remove2.addEventListener("click", () =>{
                mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                medias.splice(1, 1);
                preview2con.style.display = "none";
                if(medias[0]){
                    mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                    preview1.src = medias[0]["url"];
                    mediaCon.style.display = "block";
                    preview2con.style.display = "none";
                    preview3con.style.display = "none";
                    preview4con.style.display = "none";
                    previewcon.style.display = "none";
                    preview1con.style.display = "block";
                    preview1con.style.height = "100%";
                    if(medias[1]){
                        preview2.src = medias[1]["url"];
                        preview2con.style.display = "block";
                        previewcon.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "100%";
                    }
                    if(medias[2]){
                        preview3.src = medias[2]["url"];
                        preview3con.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                    if(medias[3]){
                        preview4.src = medias[3]["url"];
                        preview4con.style.display = "block";
                        preview1con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                }
            })

            remove3.addEventListener("click", () =>{
                mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                medias.splice(2, 1);
                preview3con.style.display = "none";
                if(medias[0]){
                    mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                    preview1.src = medias[0]["url"];
                    mediaCon.style.display = "block";
                    preview2con.style.display = "none";
                    preview3con.style.display = "none";
                    preview4con.style.display = "none";
                    previewcon.style.display = "none";
                    preview1con.style.display = "block";
                    preview1con.style.height = "100%";
                    if(medias[1]){
                        preview2.src = medias[1]["url"];
                        preview2con.style.display = "block";
                        previewcon.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "100%";
                    }
                    if(medias[2]){
                        preview3.src = medias[2]["url"];
                        preview3con.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                    if(medias[3]){
                        preview4.src = medias[3]["url"];
                        preview4con.style.display = "block";
                        preview1con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                }
            })

            remove4.addEventListener("click", () =>{
                mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                medias.splice(3, 1);
                preview4con.style.display = "none";
                if(medias[0]){
                    mediaCon = document.querySelector(".media")
                    preview1.src = medias[0]["url"];
                    mediaCon.style.display = "block";
                    preview2con.style.display = "none";
                    preview3con.style.display = "none";
                    preview4con.style.display = "none";
                    previewcon.style.display = "none";
                    preview1con.style.display = "block";
                    preview1con.style.height = "100%";
                    if(medias[1]){
                        preview2.src = medias[1]["url"];
                        preview2con.style.display = "block";
                        previewcon.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "100%";
                    }
                    if(medias[2]){
                        preview3.src = medias[2]["url"];
                        preview3con.style.display = "block";
                        preview2con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                    if(medias[3]){
                        preview4.src = medias[3]["url"];
                        preview4con.style.display = "block";
                        preview1con.style.height = "50%";
                    }
                }
            })
        </script>
```

My code can currently select multiple images then preview it. I can also delete image from preview by deleting them in the "medias" array.

So I have an javascript array "medias" where I store the image's name URL and all the file data. I also want to be upload either 4 images or 1 video.

I'm not really good with JavaScript and I know PHP more. I have been stuck trying to find ways to solve this problem for a week now. So I would really appreciate a help.

Answer (score 0):

U can pass via POST form with submit button, then upload files with php:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php